# Create a deck of cards with Faces and Suits using int Arrays

Tags: arrays, c, poker, playing-cards

I am trying to create a simple poker game Texas Hold'em style with [c](/questions/tagged/c).

At first, I tried to create a deck of cards with 2 `char` arrays:

```c
char *suits_str[4] = {"Spades", "Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs"};
char *faces_str[13] = {"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", 
                       "J", "Q", "K", "A"};
```

### Problem

Everything went well, it was pretty simple to represent the cards. But when it come to **analyzing the hands** to determine the winner, it seems like using char type values was a pretty bad idea.

So I want to change the data type of the cards into `int`:

- Suits: `0="Clubs", 1="Diamonds", 2="Hearts", 3="Spades"`
- Faces: `0="2", 1="3", 11="King", 12="Ace"`

Example:

```c
int suits[4] = {0, 1, 2, 3};
int faces[13] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12};
```

But now I don't know how to convert those int values back into their matching string values of the cards.

#### Question

What is the correct and simple approach to represent the cards using `int` Arrays?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you can see from the initializer, you do not need arrays to represent the card values and faces, simple numeric values between resp. 0 and 12 for values and 0 and 3 for faces can be used.  To convert to strings, use the card value and face as an index into the arrays `suits_str` and `faces_str`:

```
int suit = 0;   /* spades */
int face = 12;  /* ace */

printf("I am the %s of %s\n", suits_str[suit], faces_str[face]);
```

You can use enums to make you cade more readable:

```
enum suits { SPADES, HEARTS, DIAMONDS, CLUBS };
enum faces { DEUCE, THREE, FOUR, FIVE, SIX, SEVEN, EIGHT, NINE, TEN,
             JACK, QUEEN, KING, ACE };
int suit = SPADES;
int face = ACE;

printf("I am the %s of %s\n", suits_str[suit], faces_str[face]);
```

Another idea is to number cards from 0 to 51 and use formulas to extract the face and suit:

```
int card = rand() % 52;
int suit = card / 13;
int face = card % 13;

printf("I am the %s of %s\n", suits_str[suit], faces_str[face]);
```

You could create a deck of cards by initializing an array of 52 ints and shuffling it with a simple method:

```
int deck[52];
for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++) {
     /* start with a sorted deck */
     deck[i] = i;
}

for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    /* shuffle by swapping cards pseudo-randomly a 1000 times */
    int from = rand() % 52;
    int to = rand() % 52;
    int card = deck[from];
    deck[from] = deck[to];
    deck[to] = card;
}

printf("Here is a shuffled deck:\n"
for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++) {
     int card = deck[i];
     int suit = card / 13;
     int face = card % 13;
     printf("%s of %s\n", suits_str[suit], faces_str[face]);
}
```

Comment: I am not quite understanding the enums. Why do you have to create
int suit = SPADES;
int face = ACE;
Also, can you the words contain in the enum list? Or they are only for us to know which one is which?

Comment: @JasonBui: enums are useful to create typed names with a numeric value.  It is more readable to write `int suit = SPADES;` than to use the numeric value directly as in `int suit = 0;`. The 2 examples are just for illustrative purposes. The last code fragment is a more complete example of how to deal cards for your purpose.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to represent each card as single integer:

```
int getFace(int card) {
    return card/4;
}

int getSuit(int card) {
    return card%4;
}

int createCard(int face, int suit) {
    return face*4+suit;
}
```

convert them to strings only when showing to user:

```
void printCard(int card) {
    static char *suits_str[4] = {"Spades", "Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs"};
    static char *faces_str[13] = {"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9",
              "10", "J", "Q", "K", "A"};
    printf("%s %s\n", faces_str[getFace(card)], suits_str[getSuit(card)]);
}
```

and do all your computation using integers:

```
bool isOnePair(int* hand) {
    return getFace(hand[0]) == getFace(hand[1]);
}

bool isFlush(int* hand) {
    return getSuit(hand[0]) == getSuit(hand[1]);
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of using **static** char?

Comment: All invocation of `printCard` will share the same copy of `suits_str` and `faces_str`. It doesn't really make a difference here, since those arrays are never modified.

Answer (score 1):

You keep both your created arrays, and use the `int` array values as indices to your array of pointer to char.

Example:

```
 int diamonds_index = suits[1];
 char *diamonds_str = suits_str[diamonds_index];
```